# WSL2 Permission Denied in vscode when changing file name

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I recently started using WSL2 in windows 11 and in my vscode whenever I try to change a name of a file or folder, an error message pops up saying `Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/akbenn/Programs/repos/ecommerce-react-nodejs-mongodb/client/src/pages/AminPages' -> '/home/akbenn/Programs/repos/ecommerce-react-nodejs-mongodb/client/src/pages/AdminPages'`.

I even tried changing the name from vscode terminal using sudo command and it still gives me an error message saying 'Permission denied'.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried running WSL2 using administrator privilege?

Comment: Is there a command using which  WSL2 always runs with admin privillege?

Comment: Try [this](https://pureinfotech.com/always-run-windows-terminal-administrator-windows-10/) to make wsl2 shortcut and always run with admin privillege

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by creating the folder inside VSCode. If none of the options above works, you can try removing the old folders and recreate them with the command `mkdir {{ folder_name }}` inside WSL terminal.